# Using MUI modern version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-ui

According to [the mui docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/) they provide a modern folder with components written for modern browsers which they suggest could be used to target just those browsers.  How can I (or do I not need to?) setup webpack so that it rewrites imports of the form `import {Box} from "@mui/material"` (as advised by option 2 in the docs using babel-plugin-direct-import) to use the modern version?  Ideally, without having to change the import in each file to the form `import Box from "@mui/material/modern/Box"`  What about producing a separate version for the modern browsers to serve it to those browsers?

Sorry to ask such a 'how do I' style question, but googling mui and modern wasn't a very productive search :-).

Comment: Don't understand what you want to achieve. First option is best one if your webpack supports tree-shaking, which is enabled by default with create-react-app. There is not "modern" or not way to import

Comment: I assume that if I use the modern version of the imports then I'll reduce my bundle size because it won't contain code necessary for compatibility with older browsers.  I mean the mui docs specifically mention it on the bundle size page so I assume there is a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there's not a perfect way to use modern build currently. What I do is to modify `node_modules/@mui/material`'s package.json, add a `exports` field, to redirect to modern folder.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/package-exports/